# How to access scrollRect from a GameObject in the hierarchy?

Tags: input, scroll, unity-game-engine, hierarchy

I have this scrollPanel which I want to access the scrollRect in Unity3D, how can I access it in the StoreMenu script which is at the top of the hierarchy ?

Here is a snapshot of this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uF39l.jpg

Comment: I tried this,       scrollpanel = GameObject.Find("ScrollPanel");
     scrollRect = scrollpanel.GetComponent("ScrollRect");

Comment: but it complains this:

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type `UnityEngine.Component' to `UnityEngine.UI.ScrollRect'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Answer (score 1):

basically got it working like this:

```
            scrollpanel = GameObject.Find("ScrollPanel");
            scrollRect = scrollpanel.GetComponent<ScrollRect>();
            scrollRect.GetComponent<ScrollRect>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you could use method `GetComponentInChildren()`. It will go through the hierarchy and find the component you want in itself or its children.